# Promise chain order

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use the following code and there is something that a bit confuse me
if I put in the timeout 1000ms I see that the promise called in the right order
but if I change it to the following

```
  This is step 3 
  This is step 2 
  This is step 1
```

I guess that this happen since when the function is `resolved` then he proceed to the `next function` am I correct ? if this is true how can I do this chain that when the first is finished `then` he proceed to the second etc but without using the promise hell :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/2yym400j/

```
var step1 = function(ms) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log("This is step 1");
         resolve();
      }, ms);
   })
}
var step2 = function(ms) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log("This is step 2");
         resolve();
      }, ms);
   })
};
var step3 = function(ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log("This is step 3");
         resolve();
      }, ms);
   })
};


step1(500)
   .then(step2(300))
   .then(step3(200))
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
```

Comment: you need to pass a function, not the result of a function into `then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a function instead of the result of the steps.

```
step1(500)
   .then(function() { return step2(300); })
   .then(function() { return step3(200); })
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
```

Without this, you are just calling each step without "blocking" for the previous step to resolve.

Comment: Thanks This solve the issue, can you please explain why :) ?

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already gotten an answer as to why your original code didn't work, but I thought I'd show another way to approach it that is a bit more DRY than what you were doing.  You can create a single function that returns a function and then you can use that in the fashion you were using because it returns a function that will be called later which is what `.then()` wants.  So, you can do something like this:

```
function delay(t, msg) {
   return function() {
       return new Promise(function(resolve) {
           setTimeout(function() {
              console.log(msg);
              resolve();
           }, t);
       });
   }
}


delay(500, "This is step 1")()
   .then(delay(300,"This is step 2"))
   .then(delay(200, "This is step 3"))
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
});
```

Working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mbpq4g8m/

Comment: I had assumed `step1`, `step2`, and `step3` were all stand-ins for the real steps, not an actual real "print message after delay" requirement.

Comment: @JeffBowman - The point is you can curry whatever the functions are if you want an easy way to pass them parameters in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel White's comment and answer are correct, but I thought an additional explanation might help.

Your original code broke two rules:

1. `then` can't take a Promise, but it can take a function that *returns* a Promise. If you pass in anything except a function, it will be ignored, just like you passed in `null` instead.
2. As soon as you call `new Promise(someFunction)`, the `someFunction` executes asynchronously without waiting for anything. This means you can call `new Promise` from within a `then` function, but if you call it early then it won't have the delayed behavior you're expecting.

So given that each call to `stepN` returns a newly-constructed promise, I've inlined everything that happens synchronously and renamed the results `constructAndReturnPromiseN` and `constructedPromiseThatStepNReturns`. That makes your original code looks like this so all the promises happen at once:

```
constructedPromise1ThatStep1Returns
   .then(constructedPromise2ThatStep2Returns)  // BAD: Don't pass promises into then.
   .then(constructedPromise3ThatStep3Returns)  // BAD: Don't pass promises into then.
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
```

...where Daniel White's code does this:

```
constructedPromise1ThatStep1Returns
   // GOOD: The then function returns a promise that is *constructed inside* the function.
   .then(function() { return constructAndReturnPromise2(300); })
   .then(function() { return constructAndReturnPromise3(200); })
   .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
```